# How to write the fastest select function with an array and object inputs in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

Write a function called “select”.

Given an `array` and an `object`, “select” returns a new `object`, whose properties are those in the given `object` AND whose `keys` are present in the given `array`.

Notes:

- If keys are present in the given `array`, but are not in the given `object`, it should ignore them.
- It does not modify the passed in object.

(a) can filter the `array` to see if the element matches the `key` in the `obj`

(b) can create an empty `object` as a placeholder

(c) can use push or other methods to add the elements that matched the `key` to the new `object`

(d) can return new `object`

```
var arr = ['a', 'c', 'e'];
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};

function select(arr, obj) {
  var nuObj = {};
  for (var i in arr) {
    for (var key in obj) {
      if (arr[i] === key) {
        nuObj[key] = obj[key];

      }
    }
  } return nuObj;
}
  var output = select(arr, obj);
  console.log(output); // --> { a: 1, c: 3 }
```

Comment: Please check this guide on [asking homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map object and check if the key exists, then return a new object, otherwise an empty object for assigning to a single one.

> Let's have a look to this line
>
> ```
> Object.assign(...arr.map(k => k in obj ? { [k]: obj[k] } : {}))
> ```
>
> [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) takes objects and returns a single object
>
> ```
> Object.assign(                                                )
> ```
>
> [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), takes an iterable, like an array and use the items as parameters
>
> ```
>               ...
> ```
>
> For the paramters take `arr` and map an object for each item of the array
>
> ```
>                  arr.map(                                    )
> ```
>
> This is the callback for [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
>
> ```
>                          k => k in obj ? { [k]: obj[k] } : {}
> ```
>
> where a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) with a check with [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to test if a property exist in the object
>
> ```
>                               k in obj ?                 :
> ```
>
> if exist, then return a new object with a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and the value of the original object
>
> ```
>                                          { [k]: obj[k] }
> ```
>
> or if not, return an empty object, which is neutral in sense of the later `Oject.assign`
>
> ```
>                                                            {}
> ```

```js
var arr = ['a', 'c', 'e'],
    obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 },
    result = Object.assign(...arr.map(k => k in obj ? { [k]: obj[k] } : {}));

console.log(result);
```

An actual version 2020: Get entries of the object. Filter to get only wanted pairs and build a new object from the pairs.

```js
var array = ['a', 'c', 'e'],
    object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(object)
        .filter(([k]) => array.includes(k))
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I dont understand this 
"...arr.map(k => k in obj ? { [k]: obj[k] } : {})"
why the three periods? and what does "k => k in obj ? { [k]: obj[k] } : {}" do?

Comment: Please be aware this is a homework question. It is not helpful to post a direct answer to homework questions. Since it does not help the person learn the topics indicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var arr = ['a', 'c', 'e'];
var obj = {a: 1,b: 2,c: 3,d: 4};

let op = arr.reduce( (op, inp) => { 
 if(obj[inp]){
    op[inp] = obj[inp]
  }
  return op
},{})

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce()`:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'c', 'e'];
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};

var select = (arr, obj) => arr.reduce((r, c) => (c in obj ? r[c] = obj[c] : r, r), {});

console.log(select(arr, obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` over `arr`:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'c', 'e'];
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4};

let res = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => 
{
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(curr))
        acc[curr] = obj[curr];
    return acc;
}
,{});

console.log(res);
```

However, a simplified version of your code could be this one:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'c', 'e'];
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4};

function select(arr, obj)
{
    var nuObj = {};

    for (let key in obj)
    {
        if (arr.includes(key))
            nuObj[key] = obj[key];
    }

    return nuObj;
}

var output = select(arr, obj);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Be careful with `if (obj[k])`, try changing `obj.a = 0`, to see what I mean.

Comment: I catch you! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is shorter:

```
function select(arr, obj) {
  var resultObj = {};
  for (var value of arr) value in obj && (resultObj[value] = obj[value])
  return resultObj;
}
```

Works with `Object.keys` + `for` loop as well, but much slower

```
function select(arr, obj) {
  var resultObj = {}, keys = Object.keys(obj);
  for (var value of arr) keys.includes(value) && (resultObj[value] = obj[value])
  return resultObj;
}
```